# Guessing the word game

Tags: java, hangman

I'm done with this "Guessing word game" but I have a very ugly method named *startGuessing()*.

I tried to make it cleaner and more readable but I couldn't. How I can improve this method?

```
public class GameHangman {

private static String[] WORDS = {"programming", "fish", "cairo", "arabs", "quraan", "sunnah",
        "editor", "photography", "artist", "software", "write", "read", "gaming",
        "lunch", "participate", "lunch", "dinner", "house", "books", "animals"};

public static void startGame() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Choose a random word
    String word = chooseWord();

    //Start guessing game with chosen word and count missed times
    int missed = startGuessing(word, input);

    //Display result
    System.out.println("The word is " + word + (missed == 0 ? " you are correct" : " you missed " + (missed == 1 ? " one time" : " " + missed + " times")));

    //Ask for another game
    askForAnotherGame(input);
}

private static void askForAnotherGame(Scanner input) {
    System.out.print("Do you want to start another word? Enter y or no>");
    char gameCase = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (gameCase == 'y')
        startGame();
    else
        System.exit(1);
}

private static int startGuessing(String originalWord, Scanner input) {
    StringBuilder replacedWord = new StringBuilder(hideRealWord(originalWord));
    int missing = 0;
    boolean wrongGuessing;
    int wordLength = originalWord.length();

    while (wordLength > 0) {
        System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + replacedWord.toString() + " ");
        char ch = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        wrongGuessing = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < originalWord.length(); j++) {
            if (originalWord.charAt(j) == ch) {
                replacedWord.setCharAt(j, ch);
                wrongGuessing = false;
                wordLength--;
            }
            if (ch == replacedWord.charAt(j))
                System.out.println(ch  + " Already in the word");
        }
        if (wrongGuessing) {
            System.out.println(ch + " is not in the word");
            missing++;
        }

    }
    return missing;
}

private static String hideRealWord(String originalWord) {
    //System.out.println(originalWord);
    for (int i = 0; i < originalWord.length(); i++) {
        char ASTERISK = '*';
        originalWord = originalWord.replace(originalWord.charAt(i), ASTERISK);
    }
    return originalWord;
}

private static String chooseWord() {
    return WORDS[(int) (Math.random() * WORDS.length)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Break the method down

You can improve the method by trying to put it in smaller methods.

There is a `while` loop that is a good candidate for this.

The code becomes:

```
private static int startGuessing(String originalWord, Scanner input) {
        StringBuilder replacedWord = new StringBuilder(hideRealWord(originalWord));
        int missing = 0;
        boolean wrongGuessing;
        int wordLength = originalWord.length();

        while (wordLength > 0) {
            guess();
        }
        return missing;
    }
```

### Use fields in the GameHangman object

Now, you will notice things will break down, as you need the state from your method in the `guess()` method. So, you'll need to pass all the information around. You will notice this is kind of hard.

Here comes OOP around. You can store the state in an `Object`. Currently, your game is all `static` methods. If you start re-writing the game to use an instance of `HangmanGame` and use fields it will become easier.

For example, good candidates for object-state are:

- Scanner
- Current word
- Original word
- Number of incorrect guesses
- Remaining length of the word

Now, it becomes something like this:

```
public class GameHangman {

    private final static String[] WORDS = { "programming", "fish", "cairo", "arabs", "quraan", "sunnah", "editor",
            "photography", "artist", "software", "write", "read", "gaming", "lunch", "participate", "lunch", "dinner",
            "house", "books", "animals" };

    private Scanner input;
    private String originalWord;
    private int missing = 0;
    private boolean wrongGuessing;
    private int wordLength ;

    public GameHangman()
    {
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void start() {

        boolean keepPlaying = true;

        while (keepPlaying)
        {
            // Choose a random word
            this.originalWord = chooseWord();

            // Start guessing game with chosen word and count missed times
            int missed = startGuessing();

            // Display result
            System.out.println("The word is " + originalWord + (missed == 0 ? " you are correct"
                    : " you missed " + (missed == 1 ? " one time" : " " + missed + " times")));

            // Ask for another game
            keepPlaying = userWantsAnotherGame();

        }
    }

    private boolean userWantsAnotherGame() {
        System.out.print("Do you want to start another word? Enter y or no>");
        char gameCase = this.input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        return (gameCase == 'y');
    }

    private  int startGuessing() {
        StringBuilder replacedWord = new StringBuilder(hideRealWord(this.originalWord));
        this.missing = 0;
        this.wordLength = this.originalWord.length();

        while (wordLength > 0) {
            guess(replacedWord);

        }
        return missing;
    }

    private void guess(StringBuilder replacedWord) {

        System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + replacedWord.toString() + " ");
        char ch = this.input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        wrongGuessing = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.originalWord.length(); j++) {
            if (this.originalWord.charAt(j) == ch) {
                replacedWord.setCharAt(j, ch);
                wrongGuessing = false;
                wordLength--;
            }
            if (ch == replacedWord.charAt(j))
                System.out.println(ch + " Already in the word");
        }
        if (wrongGuessing) {
            System.out.println(ch + " is not in the word");
            missing++;
        }
    }

    private static String hideRealWord(String originalWord) {
        String hiddenWord = originalWord;
        for (int i = 0; i < originalWord.length(); i++) {
            char ASTERISK = '*';
            hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replace(hiddenWord.charAt(i), ASTERISK);
        }
        return hiddenWord;
    }

    private static String chooseWord() {
        return WORDS[(int) (Math.random() * WORDS.length)];
    }
}
```

### More improvements

Still lots of room for improvement, but at least the `startGuessing` is shorter and more readable.

More things to improve:

- Think of which variables you really need. For example, you don't really need word-length; you just need to check if the currently-guessed word is equal to the original word.
- `String` is immutable, so you use a `StringBuilder`. While this works, it feels kind of wrong to replace characters in a `StringBuilder`. Let's use a `char[]` to store the current state of the word that is being guessed. For easier comparison and character comparison, we can put the original word in a `char[]` as well.
- The main loop of starting a game is called recursively. This might cause a stack overflow if you play many games. Let's convert it to a `while` loop.

Now, keeping close to your solution, but with these improvements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameHangman {

    private final static String[] WORDS = { "programming", "fish", "cairo", "arabs", "quraan", "sunnah", "editor",
            "photography", "artist", "software", "write", "read", "gaming", "lunch", "participate", "lunch", "dinner",
            "house", "books", "animals" };

    private Scanner input;
    private char[] originalWord;
    private char[] currentWord;
    private int misses;

    public GameHangman() {
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void start() {

        boolean keepPlaying = true;

        while (keepPlaying) {
            // Choose a random word
            this.originalWord = chooseWord();
            this.currentWord = hideRealWord(originalWord);
            this.misses = 0;
            while (!this.originalWord.equals(this.currentWord)) {
                guess();
            }

            // Display result
            System.out.println("The word is " + String.valueOf(this.originalWord) + (misses == 0 ? " you are correct"
                    : " you missed " + (misses == 1 ? " one time" : " " + misses + " times")));

            // Ask for another game
            keepPlaying = userWantsAnotherGame();

        }
    }

    private boolean userWantsAnotherGame() {
        System.out.print("Do you want to start another word? Enter y or no>");
        char gameCase = this.input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        return (gameCase == 'y');
    }

    private void guess() {

        System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word " + String.valueOf(currentWord) + " ");
        char ch = this.input.nextLine().charAt(0);

        //Check if already made this guess
        for (int j = 0; j < this.currentWord.length; j++) {
            if (this.currentWord[j] == ch) {
                System.out.println(ch + " Already in the word");
                misses++;
                return;
            }
        }

        boolean isCorrect = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.originalWord.length; j++) {
            if (this.originalWord[j] == ch) {
                currentWord[j]=  ch;
                isCorrect = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isCorrect) {
            System.out.println(ch + " is not in the word");
            misses++;
        }
    }

    private static char[] hideRealWord(char[] originalWord) {
        char[] hiddenWord = new char[originalWord.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < originalWord.length; i++) {
            hiddenWord[i] = '*';
        }
        return hiddenWord;
    }

    private static char[] chooseWord() {
        return WORDS[(int) (Math.random() * WORDS.length)].toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I you prefer short code over *very* efficient code, you can improve the `hideRealWord` method:

```
private static String hideRealWord(String originalWord) {
    return originalWord.replaceAll(".", "*");
}
```

The `"."` is interpreted as a regular expression, and the dot means *any character except newline*.